# Print the return each time in a recursive statement (java)?

Tags: java, recursion

The project is to write a recursive method that prints the parameters and return along each step.
Here's what I have so far:

```
public static int summation(int lower, int upper){
    if (lower > upper)
        return 0;
    else{
        System.out.println("Current lower bound: " + lower);
        System.out.println("Upper bound: " + upper);
        return lower + summation(lower+1, upper);
    }
```

Its almost perfect, the only thing it's missing is printing the return every time. How do  make it do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "print the return"?

Comment: Basically print the sum every single time it goes through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
public static int summation(int lower, int upper){
    if (lower > upper) {
        System.out.println("Returning: 0");               // print before return
        return 0;
    } else{
        int result = lower + summation(lower+1, upper);

        System.out.println("Current lower bound: " + lower);
        System.out.println("Upper bound: " + upper);
        System.out.println("Returning: " + result);       // print before return
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I tried, the problem is that the output is all the upper and lower bounds, then all the sums (if that makes sense). I'm trying to make the output lower, then upper, then the current sum, and repeat.

Comment: Updated answer to print lower / upper right before returning.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int summation(int lower, int upper) {
    if (lower > upper) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        int returned = lower + summation(lower + 1, upper);
        System.out.println("Current lower bound: " + lower + " | " + "Upper bound: " + upper + " | " + "returned:" + returned);
        return returned;
    }
}
```

[image]